# MPAndroidChart label position

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I would like to modify the graph below to display the text "A" **inside** each of the line chart bubbles. How can I do that? I created a class implementing the IValueFormatter to change the labels from values to the string by calling linedataset.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter("A")). Now I just need help moving the label down a little so that it is centered inside the bubble. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {
    private String bubbletext;

    public MyValueFormatter(){
    }

    public MyValueFormatter(String bubbletext) {
        this.bubblextext = bubbletext;
    }


    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return bubbletext;
    }
}
```

[image]